# Passing data in an array between methods

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, variables, instance-variables

I'm building an array in view did load and then want to access some of the data contained within it in the viewForAnnotation method to display images in map view callouts. I've declared it below the implementation but not inside my methods, but always find that though it is loaded and processed correctly in ViewDidLoad it is always empty in the viewForAnnotation method. I've used a similar variable set up in other programs but can't see why it is not working here, sorry I'm quite new to this and its probably something simple I am missing :-/

My question is simply how can I access data loaded in viewDidLoad into the jsonTeach array in the viewForAnnotation method?

Here is my code in both methods, apart from my question everything else is working fine.

```
int annotationIndex = 0;
NSMutableArray * jsonTeach = nil;
NSString * subjectParameter = @"English";
NSString * urlString = nil;



- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];


    //HANDLE REQUEST AUTH FOR USER CURRENT LOCATION AND SHOW USER LOCATION
    self.mapView.delegate = self;

    self.locationManager= [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate=self;

    if(IS_OS_8_OR_LATER)
    {
        [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    }


    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    self.mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;


    //LOAD URL TO RETRIEVE ALL TEACHERS OR BY SUBJECT


    if (subjectParameter) {
        urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://soon.nextdoorteacher.com/apps/api/nextdoorteacher/teachers?q=%@", subjectParameter];

    }else{

        urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://soon.nextdoorteacher.com/apps/api/nextdoorteacher/teachers?q="];
    }


    // GET MY LESSONS FROM DATABASE

    NSURL *urlcc = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urlcc];
        NSError *error;
        NSMutableDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions
                                                                          error:&error];

        NSMutableArray * jsonTeach = jsonDict;
        NSLog(@"My Lessons Json == %@", jsonTeach);

        NSMutableArray *mapPointsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
        MKPointAnnotation * myAnn;

        // LOAD ANNOTATION ARRAYS INTO: mapPointsArray
        for (int i=0; i< jsonTeach.count; i++) {

            myAnn = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];

            // SET UP LOCATION
            location.latitude = [[jsonTeach[i] valueForKeyPath: @"address.latitude"]floatValue];
            location.longitude = [[jsonTeach[i] valueForKeyPath: @"address.longitude"]floatValue];
            myAnn.coordinate = location;


            //myAnn.subtitle = [jsonTeach[i] valueForKeyPath: @"rating"];
            [self.mapView addAnnotation:myAnn];



        }


    });


}



- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    // If it's the user location, just return nil.
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        return nil;

    // Handle any custom annotations.
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKPointAnnotation class]])
    {
        // Try to dequeue an existing pin view first.
        MKAnnotationView *pinView = (MKAnnotationView*)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"CustomPinAnnotationView"];
        if (!pinView)
        {
            // If an existing pin view was not available, create one.
            pinView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"CustomPinAnnotationView"];
            //pinView.animatesDrop = YES;
            pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
            pinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Tch4"];
            pinView.calloutOffset = CGPointMake(0, 32);
            pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];


            // Load and display photo using SDWEBImage

            UIImageView *photoImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];

            NSString *urlPhotoId = [jsonTeach [annotationIndex]valueForKeyPath:@"picture.id"];
            NSString *urlPhoto = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://soon.nextdoorteacher.com/img/profiles/%@.jpg", urlPhotoId];

            [photoImageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlPhoto] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mortarboard2"]];

            photoImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,50,50);
            pinView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = photoImageView;



            pinView.tag = annotationIndex;
            annotationIndex = annotationIndex +1;


        } else {
            pinView.annotation = annotation;
        }
        return pinView;
    }
    return nil;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two jsonTeach in your code. Without the whole picture of the class I assume the first one at the top of you code is a instance variable and the second one inside async block is a local variable.

In async block you assign the value to a local variable jsonTeach which will be deleted after block execution. At the same time the instance variable one remains to be nil.

In async block change this

```
NSMutableArray * jsonTeach = jsonDict;
NSLog(@"My Lessons Json == %@", jsonTeach);
```

to

```
self->jsonTeach = jsonDict;
NSLog(@"My Lessons Json == %@", self->jsonTeach);
```

Comment: Thanks @dopcn I can see exactly how that works now. Much appreciated.